# What would happen if I call CoUninitialize when the CoInitialize return RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE?

Tags: com

What would happen if I call CoUninitialize when the CoInitialize return RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE? Will it cause any issue?

Comment: Every single COM call you make will fail with CO_E_NOINITIALIZED.  Since you uninitialized COM with your inappropriate CoUnitialize() call.  Yeah, that's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to call `CoUninitialize` when you stopped all COM activity on the thread. Leaving such COM activity - in wide sense, esp. leaving referenced stubs and proxies - is very likely to cause undefined behavior and exceptions of sorts.

Since `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize` can be safely called multiple times, your unpaired `CoUninitialize` call might have different consequences depending on context.

When you had 2+ `CoInitialize` calls on the thread before your `CoUninitialize` call, nothing will happen immediately, however you are going to have issues later closer to thread termination when upper level code calls its presumably paired `CoUninitialize` calls and finally terminates COM initialization. Note that your `CoUninitialize` in this scenario does not let you change apartment mode since your call does not terminate COM on the thread (you can only change apartment mode when you uninitialized COM completely on the thread).

All in all, you should stick to the basic rule: you never call `CoUninitialize` on its own. You call `CoInitialize` and if it succeeds you must call `CoUninitialize` later on the thread when you are finished with your COM. Stepping aside from this path is likely to get you into trouble, which pretty often too painful to quickly identify and troubleshoot.

Comment: Quoting the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx): "To close the COM library gracefully on a thread, **each successful call** to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx, including any call that returns S_FALSE, must be balanced by a corresponding call to CoUninitialize."